# What is the memory layout of std::optional ? (C# interop with std::optional)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, interop

Using C# interop I need to call a function in a 3rd party C++ library. The C++ function expects a `std::optional` argument:

```
void FunctionToCall(std::optional<wchar_t const*> arg)
```

I guess I'll have to model `std::optional` as a struct containing a bool and a pointer. But I didn't find any information about the memory layout of `std::optional`. The memory layout might even be compiler-specific. So, just in case it makes a difference: It looks like the C++ library was written using Microsoft VC++.

So my question is: What is the memory layout of `std::optional` in VC++? How to do interop properly in this case?

Comment: I recommend to use c++/cli for a wrapper around the c++ code. And I don't think it's a good idea to rely on the memory layout of `std::optional` anyway.

Comment: @wohlstad of course I completely agree with you: we should not rely on a specific memory layout for std::optional. We are working with the library author to remove std::optional from the interface. But I don't think we can get a new version anytime soon, so we need a temporary solution, even if it means making some assumptions about the memory layout. A c++/cli wrapper does not necessarily solve the problem (only if we assume that this wrapper uses the same memory layout as the original library). So I prefer to not introduce an additional wrapper.

Comment: It is a c++ string (wchar_t const*) which is an array (block of continuous memory ) of wide characters (16 bit) which is terminated with a '\0.

Comment: @RobertHegner are you using PInvoke to call native call ? If so I believe it does not support c++ classes well, only raw c structs (I may be wrong there).

Comment: Regarding c++/cli - usually the practice is to mirror the c++ entities with c++/cli (i.e. .NET) ones.  So there no need to assume the memory layout of `std::optional`. You just need to maintain the logic when you convert the entity to the c++/cli counterpart.

Comment: If I would implement optional myself, I would put `bool` flag at the end of it, so compiler is able to align data stored by optional without extra padding.

Comment: Using `std::optional<wchar_t const*>` is absurd. Just use `wchar_t const*` and interpret `nullptr` as "no data".

Comment: @ALX23z I disagree. There are some nice features of optional. Anyway, I would use `std::optiona<std::wstring_view>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using clang's `pahole` tool, this is what comes out

```cpp
class optional<int> : _Optional_base<int, true, true> {
public:
};

struct _Optional_base<int, true, true> : _Optional_base_impl<int, std::_Optional_base<int, true, true> > {
    struct _Optional_payload<int, true, true, true> _M_payload; /*     0     8 */
};

class _Optional_base_impl<int, std::_Optional_base<int, true, true> > {
protected:
};

struct _Optional_payload<int, true, true, true> : _Optional_payload_base<int> {
};

struct _Optional_payload_base<int> {
    union _Storage<int, true>  _M_payload;           /*     0     4 */
    bool                       _M_engaged;           /*     4     1 */
};

union _Storage<int, true> {
    struct _Empty_byte         _M_empty;           /*     0     0 */
    int                        _M_value;           /*     0     4 */
};

struct _Empty_byte {
};
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/r4KTfYKoW

In the end this is equivalent to

```cpp
class optional<int> { 
    int value;
    bool used;
};
```

Comment: Very interesting - I didn't know this tool. Sadly it does not support VC++, but I'm just gonna assume VC++ will do it in a similar way. Will accept your answer unless a VC++ answer appears.